# how to select attributes from two tables

Tags: sql

how do I find the number of movies made by a specific actor in each year from 2 sql tables, taking startyear attribute from one table and actor name from another table?

Comment: Hi neongum, welcome to Stackoverflow! We are a community of users helping each other with programming questions. When we ask a question we should not only think about how the question can help ourself, but think about how it can help others who might have the same question. Moreover, asking a good and clear question can help us get good and clear answers. Please have a look at the article [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to be better at asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

did you mean like this?

create movie table

`create table movies (id bigint, title varchar(20), actor_id bigint, release_year int )`

insert movie example data

`insert into movies (id,title,actor_id,release_year) values (1,'movie 1',1,2022) insert into movies (id,title,actor_id,release_year) values (2,'movie 2',2,2029) insert into movies (id,title,actor_id,release_year) values (3,'movie 4',4,2030) insert into movies (id,title,actor_id,release_year) values (4,'movie 3',4,2012) insert into movies (id,title,actor_id,release_year) values (5,'movie 6',3,2022)`

create actor table

`create table actors(id bigint,actor_name varchar(20) )`

insert actor example data

`insert into actors (id,actor_name) values (1,'actor 1') insert into actors (id,actor_name) values (2,'actor 2') insert into actors (id,actor_name) values (3,'actor 3') insert into actors (id,actor_name) values (4,'actor 4')`

query

`select release_year, count(1) as [number of movies] from movies join actors on movies.actor_id = actors.id where actor_name = 'actor 4' group by release_year order by release_year asc`

the result will be like this

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUiXP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a JOIN statement,
as explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use the Joins to select Attributes from more than one table.
Need to choose which Join need to use based on the requirement.

**Inner Join**

**Right Join**

**Left Join**

**Full Join**